# Can someone walk me through this substitution?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, residue-calculus

I'm trying to solve the integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{2}{3+sin(2\theta)}d\theta$.

I know the initial trigonometric substitution changes the integral to $\int_0^\pi \frac{2}{z^2+6iz-1}dz$

and we use the substitutions $d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$ and $sin(2\theta)=\frac{z^2 - z^{-2}}{2i}$ to get there.

My best attempt is reworking the integral denominator to $6i+z^2-\frac{1}{z^2}(iz)$. May I please have some assistance?

Comment: You have a sign error in your formula for $\sin(2\theta)$. Next, once you convert to a $dz$ integral, the limits are obviously not $0$ to $\pi$. Best to change to an integral around the entire unit circle to start with and then use residues. Leave your quadratic as a quadratic and find its roots!

Comment: Thank you for the sign error remark, I told myself "It's sine, don't use plus for cosine" while I was writing this. I appreciate the outline for the steps associated with solving this integral. My class uses the Brown and Churchill text. Although they are very thorough authors I felt this section could've used a greater explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've actually substituted $z=e^{2i\theta}$ so that $2i\sin\theta=z-z^{-1}$, giving the contour integral$$\oint\frac{2dz/(2iz)}{3+(z-z^{-1})/2i}=\oint\frac{2dz}{z^2+6iz-1}.$$ The denominator is $(z+3i)^2+8$, so the poles are $(-3\pm2\sqrt{2})i$, both first-order. However, the only one that contributes by the residue theorem is the one within the $|z|=1$ contour, $(-3+2\sqrt{2})i$. This has residue $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}i}$, so the integral is $\frac{2\pi i}{2\sqrt{2}i}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I saw the substitution $cos(2\theta)=\frac{z^2+z^{-2}}{2}$ in the Brown and Churchill text and made a generalisation.

Comment: @Strakatastic Obviously, one has to choose $k$ in $z=e^{ik\theta}$ so the integral is over $2\pi$ radians. Good job!

Comment: I' m sorry. Can you walk me through the algebra with the denominator? I don't see why I wouldn't use my substitution for $sin(2\theta)$. This is the result I get from 
$sin(2\theta)=2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)$. Every time I attempt it no matter what I try I get stuck with a denominator of $\frac{z^4+6iz^2-1}{z^2}$.

Comment: @Strakatastic That's what happens if you use $z=e^{i\theta}$, which would be unhelpful anyway because it would only integrate over a range of $\pi$ radians. But if you instead use $z=e^{2i\theta}$, $2i\sin(2\theta)$=e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta}=z-z^{-1}$, which eventually gets the quadratic denominator your question mentioned (which is why I'd thought you understood that part already). I've edited the details into my answer.

Comment: Thank you for further clarification. This is the only portion of the course with which I've struggled. Residue calculus in the online lecture format is not super helpful and I've already repeatedly been to office hours on the matter. Algebra was my weakness during undergraduate, let's hope it changes before I hit the PhD-level!

Answer (score 0):

Why not to substitute $\sin2\theta=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$ to get to answer
$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{2d\theta}{3+\sin2\theta}$$
$$=2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2d\theta}{3+\sin2\theta}$$
$$=4\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{3+\frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}}$$
$$=4\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sec^2\theta d\theta}{3\tan^2\theta+2\tan\theta+3}$$
$$=\frac43\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sec^2\theta d\theta}{\left(\tan\theta+\frac13\right)^2+\frac89}$$
$$=\frac43\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\left(\tan\theta+\frac13\right)}{\left(\tan\theta+\frac13\right)^2+\left(\frac{2\sqrt2}{3}\right)^2}$$
$$=\sqrt2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)\right)$$